# Having Trouble with Simple IF ELSE

Tags: python

My code doesn't work as it always goes through the `if` section even when "K" or "k" is typed.

```
Weight = int(input("What's your weight?")) 
Unit = input('Type "L" for lbs, "K" for kilograms: ')

if Unit == "L" or "l":
     print(f' You are {Weight / 2.205} Kilograms!')

elif Unit == "K" or "k":
    print(f' You are {Weight * 2.205} pounds!')

else:
    print('You can only type "L", "l", "K" or "k".')
```

When you type your weight in kilograms it goes thru if section. I just started your help is much appreciated.

Comment: `if Unit == "L" or "l"` This is not doing what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `if` statements:

```py
if Unit == "L" or Unit == "l":
    # code
```

Therefore the others:

```py
if Unit == "L" or Unit == "l":
     print(f' You are {Weight / 2.205} Kilograms!')

elif Unit == "K" or Unit == "k":
    print(f' You are {Weight * 2.205} pounds!')
```

---

##### Addition to the question:

Use `.lower()` instead of checking if `Unit` equals both upper and lower case separately

```py
if Unit.lower() == "l":
    # code

elif Unit.lower() == "K":
    # code
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the note therein regarding questions that have "been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: Thank you sense. How could I miss that? I changed if but not elif and everything worked.

Answer (score -4):

Try adding another '=' equal sign for being  strict, cause you are basically saying 'if Unit is a String', adding the third = will say 'if Unit is strictly equal to L'

```
Weight = int(input("What's your weight?")) 
Unit = input('Type "L" for lbs, "K" for kilograms: ')

if Unit === "L" or "l":
     print(f' You are {Weight / 2.205} Kilograms!')

elif Unit === "K" or "k":
    print(f' You are {Weight * 2.205} pounds!')

else:
    print('You can only type "L", "l", "K" or "k".')
```

Comment: This only applies to Javascript (and maybe some other languages I haven't heard of), but it definitely does not apply to Python.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry :(

Comment: Note that if you choose to delete a question, any reputation points lost to downvotes will be refunded.